# How to enable tree shaking for next.js?

Tags: webpack, next.js, tree-shaking

Is there something to enable to have next.js perform tree-shaking/removal of dead code from dependencies? I've exported two objects like this:

`library.js`

```
export const foo = {foo:"foo"}
export const bar = {bar:"bar"}
```

And in my next.js app I do like this:

`page.tsx`

```
import { foo } from 'library';
console.log(foo);
```

So now I'd expect a production-build will **not** include `bar`, and indeed something appears to go right because this line is produced:

`.next/server/chunks/621.js`

```
/* unused harmony exports bar */
```

But confusingly when I load the app in the browser the network-traffic indicates the unused export **is** included:

`http://localhost:3001/_next/static/chunks/pages/page-0b2b13a7513f2849d855.js`

```
(self.webpackChunk_N_E = self.webpackChunk_N_E || []).push([[3031], {
    80621: function(e, r, n) {
        "use strict";
        ...
        const l = a.object({
            foo: "foo"
        });
        a.object({
            bar: "bar"
        });
    },
```

Why would the build identify unused exports but not remove them from the payload that's transferred to the browser? Is there a setting Next expects us to enable? Some sort of post-processing that **actually** prunes unused exports?

Comment: I don’t have an answer to this but I am a bit familiar with Next.js and I can say that it does a lot to your bundle during the build process, especially if hosted on Vercel. With that said I looked around for similar issues and didn’t find much so if you find anything please share. I’m upvoting this.

Comment: I've set up a new Next.js project here: https://github.com/gaggle/next.js-tree-shaking and it **DOES** tree-shake. So it appears I have a configuration issue in my full project to trace down 

Comment: Yikes, good luck!

Comment: if I am not mistaken the comment `/* unused harmony exports bar */` is so that UglifyJS can identify it can delete this bit.

Comment: For me if I export a function referring `createHash` of `crypto`, even though no where in my app refers to that function, nextjs seems to still includes the entire code of `crypto` when I see the big difference in the bundle size of `chunks/pages/_app.js`. I guess that inside `crypto`, there is this kind of code: `import "some-module"`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue with your example is that Next.js is able to tree-shake primitive values (boolean, string, int,...) and object/array's with primitive values.

However, webpack, the bundler used in Next.js, isn't able to identify whether a **function call** has any side-effects.

From this [Github Issue #12557](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/12557), some users report that setting `"sideEffects:false` in the `package.json` or even modifying webpack in the `next.config.js` solved this issue.

None of those worked for me. Instead, marking function's as side-effect-free using the [`/*#__PURE__*/` annotation](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/#mark-a-function-call-as-side-effect-free) worked.

Example:

```js
const createApi = (message) => {
  console.log(message);
  return () =>{}
}

export const serverApi = /*#__PURE__*/ createApi("I should only be available server side.")

export const clientApi = /*#__PURE__*/ createApi("I should only be available client side.")
```

Writing my code like above prevented `serverApi` from being included in the client bundle.

It should be noted, that the syntax of the annotation is `/*#__PURE__*/ fn()`. All other usages won't work.